# Photoshop cloning non opaque image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

Using Photoshop CS6, I have a PNG with some transparencies with soft edges.

I need to clone a semi-transparent area, but when I do that I always end up overlapping the original image, losing the original transparency.

An analog procedure is to create a transparent square/rectangle starting with just a transparent triangle and without losing the original transparency info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone your area to a new layer

When done, Command/Ctrl-click the original layer to load it as a selection.

Then add a layer mask to your clone layer. This will mask out any pixels associated with the original image.

[image: cloning]

Alternatively, you can clone areas to the same layer and merely click the option to lock transparency before you start cloning.

[image: Lock Transparency]

Comment: Hi, I ended up losing the opacity and sorting it out in a more straightforward way. I wasn't able to actually replicate that masking method - it would always overlap  , increasing the opacity level. As for the transparency lock, it was similar - it only locked fully transparent areas (i.e. empty), leaving non opaque areas alterable. But if you add some info on this, I can try, for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible answer:

https://tinyurl.com/yd3onvcp

Basically you go **Layer->Layer Mask->From Transparency**

That will make solid color layer + semi transparent mask (all appearance variation is now stored in mask). Now you can use clone stamp tool for editing that mask.

Works fine for me, thanks "MrNotPink" from Reddit :)